# discord.js music bot queue

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot for discord with a music player and I am trying to make a queue instead of replacing the song that is playing.

this is my code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

module.exports = {
name: 'p',
description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
async execute(message, args) {
    const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;

    if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
    const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
    if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissons');
    if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissons');
    if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');

    const validURL = (str) =>{
        var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
        if(!regex.test(str)){
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    if(validURL(args[0])){

        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
        const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});

        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('finish', () =>{
            voiceChannel.leave();
            message.channel.send('leaving channel');
        });

        await message.reply(`Now Playing Your Link!`)

        return
    }

    
    const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();

    const videoFinder = async (query) => {
        const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);

        return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;

    }

    const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));

    if(video){
        const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
        connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
        .on('finish', () =>{
            voiceChannel.leave();
        });

        await message.reply(`Now Playing ${video.title}`)
    } else {
        message.channel.send('No results found');
    }
}
}
```

this isn't all of my code (there is the leave command and the if command === 'join'.
If anyone can help me it would be very nice

Comment: What have you done to try to implement a queue on your own?

Comment: I don't know how to do it so I can't start

Comment: Well, on a high level, a music "queue" system would involve having an array of URLs stored outside of your command. 

Whenever a user runs the play command, it would then  either push the relevant URL to the array or immediately play it, depending on whether or not there are other URLs in the array. 

And when playing the music ends, you would need to check if there are other songs in the array: if so, begin playing the next song and remove it from the array.

It is much easier to help you if we have a base to work from that you have already tried, so we can figure out what works.